# How to restrict access by particular user to bucket using bucket level policy in minio?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, access-control, minio

I am configuring minio as S3 compatible storage.

Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html

I understood that I can limit access to the bucket using BUCKET level policy for particular user.

aws example from the linked document:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                        "public-read"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Let's consider 2 lines:

```
 "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root",
 "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"
```

as I understand `111122223333:root` and `444455556666:root` are user identifiers. But I haven't found any mc command which return me any user identifier ? I also check UI console but I haven't found anything

Could you please help ?

Comment: *"But I haven't found any mc command which return me any user identifier"* - what? What you have there is the arn of the root user of the target accounts https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html

Comment: @luk2302 but it is for amazon S3. I am configuring Minio. Sorry I missed it in my question, My bad.

Comment: Does not change that these are the ARNs of the AWS root users in two accounts. I do not understand the question.

Comment: @luk2302 I try to configure minio! minio as S3 compatible storage so it should support bucket level policy with user restriction. I can't find user identifiers in my Minio deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althouh Minio states they are s3 compatible - they don't support it and the worst thing here that I was not able to find any information in Minio documentation about inconsistecy with S3 API regarding my question.
But eventually after wasting many and many hours I was able to find closed ticket on github and it is slearly stated that it won't be implemented. It must be in documentation.

https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/9530

Answer (score 1):

```
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"
                ]
            },
```

Bucket Policies in MinIO are for anonymous access only, we did not implement this on purpose because AWS implementation in this regard is unnecessarily complex and redundant. As there are many ways to do the same thing.

You simply attach relevant policies directly to your users and provide them access via resources for relevant buckets or prefixes. This has solved 90% of the use cases 100% of the time.

There may be other requirements that might come in the future, at that point we may reconsider our position and implement it. Until then you do not really need Bucket policies with Principals.

Comment: But you also don't support IAM policies via AWS SDK as I found out here: https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/16151

`You simply attach relevant policies directly to your users` - what about case if I use external auth server via OIDC ? Could you provide detailed example ?

Comment: That would be https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/external-iam.html#minio-external-iam-oidc

Comment: I still can't find method in java SDK how to setup user policy:

https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/java/API.html

Answer (score 1):

Bucket level policy in MinIO is only for anonymous users. To restrict a user access you need to set IAM policies.

Comment: How can I achieve it in java application ? could you please provide example ?